# symfony 2 twig javascript zone

Tags: javascript, symfony

Im new to symfony and have question.

```
{% javascripts 'assets/admin/js/block.js' %}
{% endjavascripts %}
```

and in development environment it generates:

```
> <script src="/js/6222c2c_block_1.js"></script>
```

in production:

```
> <script src="/js/1b37284.js"></script>
```

and in development everything is working, in production its not. So why there is difference and what solution could be?

P.S. if I change this to:

```
 > <script src="{{ asset('assets/admin/js/block.js') }}"></script>
```

everything is working in development and production. So maybe I need to use this one?

Comment: Did you dump your assets?

Comment: no, i wasnt :) thank you, it worked